# analyzing SO posters' experience level

Tags: discussion

I thought it would be interesting to plot the 'experience level,' as determined by medals or number of posts,  vs calendar time  for questions tagged with "R" (posted to SO ).  Assuming I teach myself some of the R-packages for general data mining, is there an accessible dbase within SO that could be used for such a purpose?
(Not that I would turn down a fully functional solution to this problem :-) )

Comment: Maybe this? http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/usage

Comment: I have no objection to moving the question -- I figured it was rather "meta" .

Comment: or https://api.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks to all commenters and answerers.  Off I go to scrape data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best place to find the data would be in *[Predict Closed Questions on Stack Overflow](http://www.kaggle.com/c/predict-closed-questions-on-stack-overflow)*. This is a preprocessed dataset from Stack Overflow to predict if a question will be closed or not.

The next resource is the [Stack Overflow Creative Commons dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/).

And to get an insight into some fun stuff you could do with the data, check out the paper *[Discovering Value from Community Activity on Focused
Question Answering Sites: A Case Study of Stack Overﬂow](http://www-cs.stanford.edu/people/jure/pubs/sof-kdd12.pdf)* (published 2012-08-12) from a bunch of heavy hitters.